# How to initialize log4j 2.0 ? LogManager.getContext brings a null pointer exception

Tags: java, log4j

I'm trying to use the current version 2.0 beta of log4j.
I have included all necessary jar files of log4j.
Starting the application brings only a:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:203)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager$PrivateManager.getContext(LogManager.java:62)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.reconfigure(LogManager.java:50)
    at org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure(BasicConfigurator.java:28)
```

Neither

```
org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

nor

```
  private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger("...");
```

work anymore.

Does anyone know what the problem could be ?

Greetings

Mike

Comment: Have you really added `log4j-core-*.jar` jar beside `log4j-api-*.jar`?

Comment: If he didn't add them, he would get `ClassNotFoundException`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the BasicConfigurator is not implemented in log4j v2.  You're getting access to a BasicConfigurator class through the bridge from log4j 1.2 to log4j 2. If you're using Log4j v2, you can't use BasicConfigurator anymore.

The bridge library is named log4j-1.2-api-2.2.jar at this time.  It's been a few years since this question was asked.

So, if you have the bridge you can access most Log4j 1.2 classes, but they may not have an implementation behind them. BasicConfigurator is an example of that situation.  This is why you're getting a null pointer exception.

If you're ok with a similar setup but the level being set to Error instead of Debug, you don't need to do any configuration.  If you want log messages at a lower level than Error, it appears that you'll either need to create your own version of BasicConfigurator, or you'll need to put a log4j2.[xml|yaml|json] file on your classpath.